# li elements fill ul width with same spacing between element in Horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal menu navigation using `ul` as main menu container and `li` as menu list item, i'm using display table for `ul` and table-cell for `li`, so when each `li` will fit to ul width, the problem is the gap between each words menu item is not the same, the cause is because i set padding between `li` elements but if i get rid off the padding, it won't has any gap at all,i need to maintain the gap between each words menu item is the same even when there is a word break inside the `li` element, and i need to maintain the responsiveness of the display.

[image]

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/qb9yvh9p/14/)

css code:

```
body{
  background-color: #ff2;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
ul { 
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color: #F25800;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
li { 
    display:table-cell; 
    text-align:center;
    padding: 10px 12px;
} 
li:hover{
  background-color: #64b448;
}
li a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
li a span{
  font-size: 13px; 
  color: #fff;
}
```

html code:

```
<ul>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/kebutuhan-rumah.html" class="level-top"><span>Kebutuhan Rumah</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/kebutuhan-pribadi.html" class="level-top"><span>Kebutuhan Pribadi</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/makanan-minuman.html" class="level-top"><span>Makanan & Minuman</span></a> 
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/kebutuhan-kantor.html" class="level-top"><span>Kebutuhan Kantor</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/otomotif.html" class="level-top"><span>Otomotif</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/listrik-teknik.html" class="level-top"><span>Listrik & Teknik</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/alat-bangunan.html" class="level-top"><span>Alat Bangunan</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/elektronik.html" class="level-top"><span>Elektronik</span></a> 
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/pakaian.html" class="level-top"><span>Pakaian</span></a> 
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/pecah-belah.html" class="level-top"><span>Pecah Belah</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/kesehatan.html" class="level-top"><span>Kesehatan</span></a> 
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/mainan-hobi.html" class="level-top"><span>Mainan & Hobi</span></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if you may notice, there is no gap between li ... it's the padding your defined and their width (add a background to li)

Comment: @TemaniAfif but there's a gap between each words

Comment: i know, but it's not a gap between li elements ... and background to them and you will see ... you have padding specified on li and text align center, so the gap is coming from this

Comment: @TemaniAfif but i only definde the padding for top and bottom

Comment: `li { 
    display:table-cell; 
    text-align:center;
    padding: 10px 12px;
}` --> you have 10px for top/bottom and 20px for left/right ... add a background like i told you and you will understand :)

Comment: can u show me the level-top class in the css?

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh yeah my bad sorry, but if i get rid off the padding right and left there'll be no gap

Comment: yes and because this how table work and this what am trying to explain from the beginning :) you have not gap .. all you see are the styling insde the li ... the padding and the text-align center, and the width of the element

Comment: @TemaniAfif so what's the best solution for this case?

Comment: you can for example use flex instead of table .. remove all right/left padding and control with margin to be sure it will be exactly the same

Comment: @TemaniAfif can you show it by modificating given fiddle example?

Comment: here us an idea https://jsfiddle.net/qb9yvh9p/41/

Comment: @TemaniAfif its not good, i've modified it like this https://jsfiddle.net/qb9yvh9p/43/ the only problem is the text wont vertical align center

Comment: use `center` with align-items

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{
  background-color: #ff2;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
ul { 
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    background-color: #F25800;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
li { 
    display:inline-flex; 
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 1;
    padding: 10px 12px;
    text-align:center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 12px;
} 
li:hover{
  background-color: #64b448;
}
li a{
  text-decoration:none;
}
li a span{
  font-size: 13px; 
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/kebutuhan-rumah.html" class="level-top"><span>Kebutuhan Rumah</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/kebutuhan-pribadi.html" class="level-top"><span>Kebutuhan Pribadi</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/makanan-minuman.html" class="level-top"><span>Makanan & Minuman</span></a> 
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/kebutuhan-kantor.html" class="level-top"><span>Kebutuhan Kantor</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/otomotif.html" class="level-top"><span>Otomotif</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/listrik-teknik.html" class="level-top"><span>Listrik & Teknik</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/alat-bangunan.html" class="level-top"><span>Alat Bangunan</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/elektronik.html" class="level-top"><span>Elektronik</span></a> 
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/pakaian.html" class="level-top"><span>Pakaian</span></a> 
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/pecah-belah.html" class="level-top"><span>Pecah Belah</span></a>
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/kesehatan.html" class="level-top"><span>Kesehatan</span></a> 
   </li>
   <li class="ui-menu-item level0 classic parent ">
      <div class="open-children-toggle"></div>
      <a href="http://test.com/mainan-hobi.html" class="level-top"><span>Mainan & Hobi</span></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the applicable code.

1. Changed the display of `ul` to `flex`
2. Set `li`'s display to `inline-flex`, configured it to wrap, and adjusted sizing with `flex: 1`. Used `align-items: center` to center it vertically.